# How to define Boosts tests to run in code?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, boost, boost-test

Using Boost.Test I'm trying to specify the [`BOOST_TESTS_TO_RUN`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/test/doc/html/utf/user-guide/runtime-config/reference.html) environment variable in code, so that only some tests will be executed. Using `#define BOOST_TESTS_TO_RUN`.

The command line parameter [`--run_tests`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/test/doc/html/utf/user-guide/runtime-config/run-by-name.html) works fine. But I'd like to do it via the environment variable in order to have a single `main.cpp` in which I can select different suites and modules.

But I'm not sure on how to specify it, or where. Should it be before including boost? What if I have different cpp files with different test suites?

module_A.cpp

```
#include "SomeHeader.h"
#define BOOST_TESTS_TO_RUN // ??
#include "boost/test/unit_test.hpp"
BOOST_AUTO_TEST_SUITE( moduleA );
BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE( test1 ){}
BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE( test2 ){}
BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE( test3 ){}
BOOST_AUTO_TEST_SUITE_END();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Boost UTF was not designed that way. If you really want to en-/disable certain tests from your code, you could use manual registration for all your tests and define a master test suite, in which you need to manually register all tests. See the [master-test-suite](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/test/doc/html/utf/user-guide/test-organization/master-test-suite.html) documentation and other pages about manual test registration. You could then comment-out certain tests you don't want to run.

However, I do not recommend this approach. It's too easy to forget tests and thus harder to maintain. For debugging you could easily run the test executable by hand and use the command-line parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Check instead the new documentation of [--run_test](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/libs/test/doc/html/boost_test/utf_reference/rt_param_reference/run_test.html) that explains that the environment variable `BOOST_TEST_RUN_FILTERS` can be used for that (also existing in the previous version of boost, but the environment variable usage is less obvious from the doc).

Basically, you compile your `main.cpp` only once with all tests (enabled by default) and then run them selectively from the `BOOST_TEST_RUN_FILTERS` environment variable.

I do not see a problem in doing this, especially wrt. the design of boost.test.